# How to deploy a Django website that developed on Pycharm IDE (windows 10) to AWS EC2 or Elastic Bean?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, windows-10, pycharm

I recently build a Django website in local with **Pycharm IDE**. **I am using window 10.** The website is almost done. Now I need to research how to deploy it on the AWS EC2 or Elastic Bean. The reason of choosing AWS is I want to learn how to use AWS. Any clues, tips or document will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you already know how to setup a web server for django?